# Mailmerge calculations are not calculating correctly.

Tags: syntax, mailmerge, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate the interest rate for a legal form I am creating at work. In order to get that rate you need to take the current balance X legal rate of interest X 0.01 / 365. Here is what I have currently written that is not calculating correctly.

```
{={Principal}-{Paid}*{InterestRate}*0.01/365}
```

When I run the mergefield "as is", on our test account that has a principle balance of 5,000 a paid balance of 0.00 and an interest rate of 10%(10.00) it comes out = 5,000 instead of 1.36.

I have searched forums and the Microsoft's support site and stackoverflow and only found info on what operators are allowed and examples of basic syntax of addition, subtraction, and division. None that where showing a combination of these. Can you please be another set of eyes and help me see where my syntax is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to deal with order of operations.  In this example, {Paid}*{InterestRate}*0.01/365} is executed first (multiplication/division), then the subtraction takes place.

Just add parens around {Principal}-{Paid} and it should work.

{ = **(** { Principal } - { Paid } **)** * { InterestRate } * 0.01 / 365 }

Comment: I just ran it again with the parentheses and it gave me a syntax error this time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message?  As a note, I do not believe copying/pasting will generate a valid formula.

Comment: The value returned for field1 is : $5000.00
The value returned for field2 is: $0.00

The merge field is trying to subtract field1 from field2 and I think it is causing an error because it is a string maybe?

If that is the case is there anyway to convert field1 and field2 to a decimal and subtract them?

Comment: Thanks for the help in reminding me of my order of operations. I figured out that the problem was more than just that. The merge data I was using were varchars instead of integers. When I converted the merge data to integers, it worked. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer though, because if I had the merge data as integers to begin with, my only problem would have been order of operations. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a syntax error if the Regional Settings in Windows Control panel (or in Mac System Preferences) have, e.g. £ instead of $ as the currency symbol. To avoid that, you can try something more like

```
{ SET myPrincipal { MERGEFIELD Principal } 
}{ SET myPaid { MERGEFIELD Paid } 
}{ SET myInterestRate { MERGEFIELD InterestRate } 
}{ =(myPrincipal-myPaid) * myInterestRate * 0.01 /365 }
```

If you have mixed currencies, that may end up showing a currency symbol where the symbol matches the control panel setting, and a plain number where it doesn't. Adding a \#0.00 to the end of the { = } will probably fix that.

Comment: After reading and thinking about your answer, I thought that maybe the syntax error was caused by the data I am merging in. The first two are varchar's the other is a integer. So I converted my merge data to integers and it worked. Thanks for sparking that thought.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I had been scratching my head for months wondering why the exact same word calculation worked on one computer and not the other - one was set to the wrong locale!